# How Do I Cancel and Restart a Timed Event in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, events, delay, cancellation

I have a `sliderValueChange` function which updates a `UILabel`'s text.  I want for it to have a time limit until it clears the label's text, but I also want this "timed clear" action to be cancelled & restarted or delayed whenever the `UISlider` is moved within the time limit before the "timed clear" action takes place.

So far this is what I have:

```
let task = DispatchWorkItem {
  consoleLabel.text = ""
}
func volumeSliderValueChange(sender: UISlider) {

  task.cancel()

  let senderValue = String(format: "%.2f", sender.value)
  consoleLabel.text = "Volume: \(senderValue)"

  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 3, execute: task)  
}
```

Obviously, this approach does not work, since `cancel()` apparently cannot be reversed.. (or at least I don't know how).  I also don't know how to start a new task at the end of this function which will be cancelled if the function is recalled..

Am I going about this the wrong way?  Is there something I am overlooking to make this work?

Comment: I would an NSTimer. You still need to cancel (invalidate) and reschedule the timer if you want to change the timer period. But if you do want to use a task, yes, you will need to create and submit a new task.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a timer:

```
weak var clearTimer: Timer?
```

And:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  startClearTimer()
}

func startClearTimer() {
  clearTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(
    timeInterval: 3.0,
    target: self,
    selector: #selector(clearLabel(_:)),
    userInfo: nil,
    repeats: false)
}   

func clearLabel(_ timer: Timer) {
   label.text = ""
}

func volumeSliderValueChange(sender: UISlider) {
   clearTimer?.invalidate()  //Kill the timer
   //do whatever you need to do with the slider value
   startClearTimer()  //Start a new timer
}
```

Comment: @PlateReverb, as in this answer, the declaration is `func clearLabel(_ timer: Timer)`, it makes `#selector(clearLabel(_:))` perfectly valid. Your [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15732441) on the other hand is wrong and would introduce the following error: `error: use of unresolved identifier 'clearLabel(timer:)'
            selector: #selector(clearLabel(timer:))`

Comment: @Cœur This is strange... because with `#selector(clearLabel(_:))` I get the error `Use of unresolved identifier 'clearLabel'` and changing `_` to `timer` fixes it.  I encountered a similar problem before, and found the solution on an SO Q&A to the same kind of problem.  I wish I knew why this error occurred and why this solution works for me, and not you...?

Comment: Oh, @PlateReverb, I only just noticed that you made _two_ suggested edits. Well, the first one was correct. I'm criticizing the second one, where the signature of the function is different from before: Duncan changed it from `func clearLabel(timer: Timer)` to `func clearLabel(_ timer: Timer)` if you look at the history

Comment: @Cœur Oh!  I missed that change.  This explains it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are cancelling the wrong thing. You don't want to cancel the task; you want to cancel the *countdown* which you got going when you said `asyncAfter`.

So use a DispatchTimer or an NSTimer (now called a Timer in Swift). Those are counters-down that can be cancelled. And then you can start counting again.